# Multiple regEx matches

Tags: jquery, regex

I am matching words that begin with certain prefixes.

This regex is working well for me but I am having trouble applying multiple terms in one match.

- matching prefix 're': `/re\S+/g;`

I thought it would work with

- matching prefix 're' and 'http': `/(re|http)\S+/g;`

However the latter only returns matches from the second term.

Here is the full code:

```
    function replacePrefix(input){
        var re = /(#)\S+/g;         
        var specials = [];
        var match;
        while(match = re.exec(input)){
            $('#text').html(input.replace(specials[0], "<span class='special'>"+specials[0]+"</span>"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `input` might be and what you want to match, or not match.

Comment: eg "This is a sentence with really great urls in it like http://www.coolurl.com"

would return "really" and "http://www.coolurl.com"

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to achieve with the code in your while loop? Do you want to append a new span element to `$('#text')` containing the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replacePrefix(input){
    var re = /\b(?:re|http)\S+/g;         
    var specials = [];
    var match;
    while(match = re.exec(input)){
        console.log(match);
    }
}
replacePrefix("This is a sentence with really great urls in it like http://coolurl.com";);

["really"]
["http://coolurl.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem was some rogue characters. Thanks for the improved regex!